# Notepad++ process line with no number at beginning

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some files where some lines do not begin with a number. Right now I'm finding them with the regular expression `^(?!"9|"2|"7|"5|"1)`  (correct lines begin with these numbers) and delete the first character to go to the line above.

I.e.

```
"99898989"
"77777777"
characters
"55555555"
```

will become:

```
"99898989"
"77777777"characters
"55555555"
```

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: You can replace `(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)(?!"9|"2|"7|"5|"1)(.*)` with `\2` to achieve this result.

Comment: I've no experience with Notepad++, but if you can do a multi-line regex something like this should work: `s/^("[12579][^\n]*)\n/\1/g`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your newlines are `\n` characters, you can replace

```
$\n(?!"[12579])
```

with an empty string. Basically, we put ourselves at the end of a line, and check that the next line doesn't start with `"[12579]`.

If it doesn't, we erase the newline character: see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/iT1gW0).

Answer (score 0):

In order to deal with any kind of line break:

Find what: `\R(?!"[12579])`
Replace with: `nothing`

`\R`  stands for any of `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`.